# WinForms - How do you get the size a Control "wants" to be?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

When a `Control` is docked in a container (like a `Panel`) and is too wide to be shown (so a scroll bar appears), `Control.Width` seems to return the visible width of the Control (the top arrow in the picture).

How do you get the width that the Control "wants" to be? i.e. its full width that you'd see if you didn't have to scroll (the bottom arrow in the picture).

[alt text http://img19.imageshack.us/img19/372/size.png](http://img19.imageshack.us/img19/372/size.png)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two different properties of controls that you might find useful for this purpose. There is the DefaultSize which is the Size of the control when it is initially created, and then there is the PreferredSize which is the size the control can fit into so to speak. All controls have these properties and PreferredSize should be the one you're looking for.

Answer (score 9):

`Bounds` is the actual size its drawn at

`ClientSize` is the size minus any scroll bars

`Control.PreferredSize` is what you want

Answer (score 1):

`Control.HorizontalScrollbar.Maximum`, or `Control.VerticalScrollbar.Maximum` should return the maximum size required. It may return a slightly small amount as it may cut padding off.